# Is there any way to find the exact Query responsible for replication lag?

Tags: mysql, replication

I've tried checking slowquery.log and binlog.

Slow query log kind of helps but not all the time.

Binlog entries are inaccurate. I used the following command to check binlog.

```
show binlog events in <binlog name> from <log position> limit <n>;
```

Answer (score 1):

`log_slow_slave_statements = ON` in the Slave's `my.cnf`.  Also `long_query_time=1`.  Turn on the slow log; wait a day; look in the slowlog.  `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest` will summarize the slowlog, putting the 'worst' query first.

(From the Changelogs)
----- 2013-04-23 5.7.1 Milestone 11 & 2013-04-18 5.6.11 -- Bugs Fixed -- -----

> The --log-slow-admin-statements (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-admin-statements
>   ) and --log-slow-slave-statements (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-slave-statements
>   ) command options now are exposed at runtime as the
>   log_slow_admin_statements (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_slow_admin_statements
>   ) and log_slow_slave_statements (
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#sysvar_log_slow_slave_statements ) system variables. Their values can be examined using SHOW VARIABLES
>   ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-variables.html ). The
>   variables are dynamic, so their values can be set at runtime. (The
>   options were actually replaced by the system variables, but as system
>   variables can be set at server startup, no option functionality is
>   lost.) (Bug #59860, Bug #11766693)

In older versions, the command line `--log-slow-slave-statements` existed even though the variables did not.

Comment: " log_slow_slave_statements = ON in the Slave's my.cnf. Also long_query_time=1. Turn on the slow log; wait a day; look in the slowlog.  mysqldumpslow -s t or pt-query-digest will summarize the slowlog, putting the 'worst' query first."



Hi Rick, does above variables need only to be enabled in slave node ?
also I've read in MySQL 5.7 manual

Note that all statements logged in row format in the master will not be logged in the slave's slow log, even if log_slow_slave_statements is enabled.

Comment: @JD - The first setting is not relevant for the Master.  And, OK, simple RBR statements are not relevant.  Still, there could be a slow DDL (eg, `ALTER`) that comes through replication.

Comment: so can we enable those variables only in slave ? or slow query logging must be enabled as well in master node ? e.g. in master node long_query_time and slow_query_log then in slave node these 2 variables + log_slow_slave_statements, which will suffice ?

Comment: @JD - Slave lag is likely to be a Slave issue; so focus there.  The parameters I mentioned are not sufficient to turn on the slowlog.  Read the manual _for your version_ to figure out how to do that.